# Take data from all books to some table

Tags: excel, excel-2003, vba

I am very new in EXCEL (especially in VBA). I try to write logic that:

go to all open books, if some book has sheet with name "Test", it should take data from named range "Table" and then append it to the Table1 from sheet ALLDATA in book ALLDATABOOK. I try to write this, can someone help me?

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Dim book As Object
    Dim lst As ListObject
   Dim iList As Worksheet
   For Each book In Workbooks

   For Each iList In book.Sheets
        If iList.Name = "Test" Then

        book.Sheets(iList.Name).Activate
Range("Table").Select


        End If
    Next

   Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (written for Excel 2007+, may not work for earlier versions)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim book As Workbook
    Dim lst As ListObject
    Dim iList As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range

    Dim wbAllDataBook As Workbook
    Dim shAllData As Worksheet

    ' Get reference to ALLDATA table
    Set wbAllDataBook = Workbooks("ALLDATABOOK.xlsm")  '<-- change to suit your file extension
    Set shAllData = wbAllDataBook.Worksheets("ALLDATA")
    Set lst = shAllData.ListObjects("Table1")

    For Each book In Workbooks
        ' Use error handler to avoid looping through all worksheets
        On Error Resume Next
        Set iList = book.Worksheets("Test")
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            ' sheet not present in book
            Err.Clear
            On Error GoTo 0
        Else
            ' If no error, iList references sheet "Test"
            On Error GoTo 0
            ' Get Reference to named range
            Set Rng = iList.[Table]
            ' Add data to row below existing data in table.  Table will auto extend
            If lst.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
                ' Table is empty
                lst.InsertRowRange.Resize(Rng.Rows.Count).Value = Rng.Value
            Else
                With lst.DataBodyRange
                    .Rows(.Rows.Count).Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rng.Rows.Count).Value = Rng.Value
                End With
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

---

**Update:**

To use with Excel 2003 replace

```
If lst.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
```

with

```
If Not lst.InsertRowRange Is Nothing Then
```

Comment: thaks, but I am using excel 2003, i will try

Comment: If future please tag excel questions with version

Comment: ok, I see some trouble in code: it take only the first line from each of my named range, (if I check named rang there is more then one line)

Comment: Oh, ok.  Just use `Resize` to size the destination range - see update

Comment: please, see my next question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511660/take-data-from-named-range-excel-vba that is a continuation of the question